# Django HTML for loop not showing corresponding values

Tags: html, django, django-views

I am using a for loop in an HTML Template, it recognizes the fact that they are there but it does not show them in the page like it should.

my views:

```
    person = []
    x = people.objects.filter(deal='q')
    for person in x:
         print(person.name)
         if person.paid_status == True:
             person.append(lender)
     return render(request, '.html', {'person': person})
```

my template:

```
<div>
    {% if person %}
        There are {{ person|length }} persons.
        {% for p in person %}
    <p> {{ p.name }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
         <p> As of now no persons have appeared. </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

in the console it prints the persons name correctly so I am confused why it does not work in the HTML

All I see is that there are 2 persons(which is correct) but then it does not list them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the variable **person** inside your loop.

Change the list *person* to *persons* and it should work fine.

Your view:

```
persons = []
x = people.objects.filter(deal='q')
for person in x:
     if person.paid_status == True:
         persons.append(person)
 return render(request, '.html', {'persons': persons})
```

Your template:

```
<div>
    {% if persons %}
        There are {{ persons|length }} persons.
        {% for p in persons %}
        <p> {{ p.name }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
         <p> As of now no persons have appeared. </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, by overwhelming the variable what did you mean?

Comment: On the first line you do `person = []`, then in the loop you do `for person in x:`. When you do that, the variable *person* being used to iterate the list *x* is overwriting the list *person* you just created 2 lines above. If my answer is the correct answer, please, mark as the correct one, it would help me a lot.